# How to create and write directly to text console buffer in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, console, x86-64

How can I create a new text console terminal with a certain size and how do I map the memory of the console buffer so that I can write directly into it? I dont want to use any emulator, just the normal linux console on ubuntu.

Comment: Are you talking about the text console terminal?  Or a terminal *window*, i.e. writing your own terminal emulator with X11 or other graphics library?  Existing terminal emulators like xterm and konsole don't expose an API that lets you write ASCII characters into memory, only the normal TTY interface with ANSI escape codes.

Comment: I mean the text console terminal

Comment: Have a look at the system calls `chvt` makes to see how to switch the actual console to a new virtual terminal, and `resizecons(8)` / `setfont(8)` - use strace on them or check their source code to see what system calls they use.  For drawing on the screen, see `vcs(4)` / `vcsa(4)` I think.

Comment: Ill do that; why are there so few resources on this? And isnt there like a documentation for linux developers for stuff like this?

Comment: Probably there is, I just don't know it off the top of my head.  Since your googling didn't turn up anything useful, strace on some programs would give you some more things to google on and maybe find some guides.

Comment: Where should I begin if I wanted to write my own terminal emulator? Or before that just creating a window and drawing something to it?

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab People rarely use these for graphics.  That's what X11 and libraries like SDL are for.

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab To make a graphics window, you need to talk to the X server.  There are a few libraries to do that, but you can also do it without one.  Start by reading the X11 protocol specification.

Comment: @EarlofLemongrab: You should begin with a tutorial for doing that, for your choice of graphics interface / library.  (e.g. X11, Wayland, or other display managers (or libraries that abstract that, e.g. OpenGL), or [Linux console framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) graphics mode like SVGAlib can use, or whatever.)